# C# applying click event listener in "Code-Created" Buttons

Tags: c#, button, onclick, onclicklistener

I have created buttons by code as:

```
        List<Button> buttons = new List<Button>();
        ArrayList myTopics = sqlFunction.loadTopicList();
        for (int i = 0; i < myTopics.Count; i++)
        {
            Button newButton = new Button();
            buttons.Add(newButton);
            panel1.Controls.Add(newButton);
         }
```

Now I have to add click event listener to these buttons. What I need is like:

```
         if(ClickedButton.Text =="something")
          {
              //do something
          }
```

When looked in UI, this form contains only the empty panel - panel1. Can you please give any idea how would I give add this click event ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't remember well enough the events on the buttons since I'm on my phone. But, you should do something like this:

(Assuming you are using Winforms)

in your loop:

```
newButton.Click += new EventHandler(do_something);
```

outside the loop:

```
void do_something(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn.Text == "something")
    {
        //now, do something cool  
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, thanks... I improved the answer. Good luck with those buttons